# rowsums of specific columns filling a condition

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate, rowsum

I'm trying to sum specific columns of my data that fills  some condition,
like the example underneath

```r
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
set.seed(123)
data=data.frame(id=1:4,
                v1=sample(c("a","b"),4,TRUE),
                v2=sample(c("a","b"),4,TRUE),
                v3=sample(c("a","b"),4,TRUE),
                v4=sample(c("a","b"),4,TRUE),
                v5=sample(c("a","b"),4,TRUE),
                v5=sample(c("a","b"),4,TRUE)
                )
data%>%
  rowwise()%>%
  mutate(across(v1:v4,~sum(.x=="a")))%>%
  mutate(n_a=sum(c(v1,v2,v3,v4)))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 8
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      id    v1    v2    v3    v4 v5    v5.1    n_a
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <int>
#> 1     1     1     1     1     0 b     a         3
#> 2     2     1     0     1     1 a     b         3
#> 3     3     1     0     0     0 a     a         1
#> 4     4     0     0     0     1 a     a         1
```

here n_a is the sum of vars from v1 to v4 that have the value a
could have a better implementation of my code ?

- one mutate line with no transformation of other vars ?
- can i use sum with something like v1:v4 ?

<sup>Created on 2023-07-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `rowSums` with `pick` -

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(n_a = rowSums(pick(v1:v4) == "a", na.rm = TRUE))

#  id v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v5.1 n_a
#1  1  a  a  a  b  b    a   3
#2  2  a  b  a  a  a    b   3
#3  3  a  b  b  b  a    a   1
#4  4  b  b  b  a  a    a   1
```

Answer (score 2):

A similar question was asked a few days ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76763484/22282823).

You can use `rowSums` with `==`.

```
data$n_a <- rowSums(data[, 2:6] == "a")

data
  id v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 n_a
1  1  a  a  a  b  b   3
2  2  a  b  a  a  a   4
3  3  a  b  b  b  a   2
4  4  b  b  b  a  a   2
```

The columns to count over can be customised as required too.

```
data$n_a <- rowSums(data[, -1] == "a")
data$n_a <- rowSums(data[, c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5")] == "a")
data$n_a <- rowSums(data[, startsWith(colnames(data), "v")] == "a")
```

Answer (score 1):

your code is the right way, however to shorten the code you can choose the opposite way of using `across()` inside `sum()` in your second line and define a function inside `across()` to calculate `"a"` characters:

```
library(tidyverse) 
data %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(n_a=sum(across(v1:v4, \(x) x=="a")))

     id v1    v2    v3    v4    v5    v5.1    n_a
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
1     1 a     a     a     b     b     a         3
2     2 a     b     a     a     a     b         3
3     3 a     b     b     b     a     a         1
4     4 b     b     b     a     a     a         1
```

Comment: so to have it in the same writing as in the dplyr ref page of across function
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html
my_fun = function(x) x=="a" ; 
data %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(n_a=sum(across(v1:v4, ~my_fun(.x)))) ; 
is there a dplyr ref page for the \(x) type of scripting